# Changing CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE through user input with openCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera, computer-vision

I am trying to manually control the exposure of a USB camera with OpenCV by pressing buttons on my keyboard. I got the code working with writing in the exposure value and then running it, but I'm looking for a live adjust ability.

```
import cv2


# Connect to IMX291 (1)
captureDevice = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
# Loop through every frame until we close our webcam
key2 = cv2.waitKey(0)
# Exposure
exposure = 0

captureDevice.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,exposure)



# Gain
captureDevice.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_GAIN,1)

# Window Resolution
captureDevice.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
captureDevice.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)


while captureDevice.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = captureDevice.read()

    # Show image 
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)

    # Checks whether q has been hit and stops the loop

    key = cv2.waitKey(0)



    if key == ord('q'): 
        break
    captureDevice.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,exposure)
    if key2 == ord('e'):
        exposure += 0.5
    if key2 == ord('d'):
        exposure -= 0.5


# Releases the webcam
captureDevice.release()
# Closes the frame
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the code I've been working on. With the user keyboard inputs the video is displayed as a solid image and does not change exposure when I press the E and D keys. Is CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE even adjustable like this?

Comment: look at your `waitKey` call. look at the documentation for `waitKey`.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks that appears to have given me a video feed, but for some odd reason the exposure doesn't go up on the camera when the keys are pressed on the keyboard. Theoretically the exposure should go up by some specified amount.

Comment: drive it up to 255. if that doesn't do it, your camera doesn't support this parameter

Comment: key = cv2.waitKey(1)